# Setting Expires and Cache-Control headers for images that are being uploaded to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using an npm package called `node-s3-client` which is a high-level wrapper for the `aws-sdk` for Node.js, to upload a local project directory to an S3 bucket.

Using that package, I'm passing some metadata to my files, namely key value pairs for `Expires` and `Cache-Control`. I'm uploading an entire directory which consists of HTML, JS, CSS, JPEG files. However when I check my S3 bucket, the headers that I'm setting **only applies** to JS and CSS files, these headers are not applied to images.

I've gone through the documentation of the package and aws-sdk but I can't seem to find what causes the issue of selectively applying my metadata to some files and not applying to others.

Here's my config object:

```
const s3 = require('node-s3-client')

const s3Config= {
    localDir: './dist',
    deleteRemoved: false,
    s3Params: {
        Bucket: 'cdn',
        Prefix: 'dist/',
        Metadata: {
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=31536000',
            'Expires': oneYearLater(new Date())
        }
    }
}

const client = s3.createClient({
    s3Options: {
        accessKeyId: KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: ACCESS_KEY,
        signatureVersion: 'v4',
        region: 'us-east-2',
        s3DisableBodySigning: true
    }
})

client.uploadDir(s3Config)
```

What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 11):

I think you have an issue on how you set up the params for your object to upload. Try:

```
const s3Config= {
    localDir: './dist',
    deleteRemoved: false,
    s3Params: {
        Bucket: 'cdn',
        Prefix: 'dist/',
        CacheControl: 'max-age=31536000',
        Expires: oneYearLater(new Date())
    }
}
```